# How can i get other devices ip connected to same network in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, wifi

I want to develop a WP8 application which list all devices connected to the local network in which my windows phone is connected via WiFi. So is there any class which list the devices or atleast information about other devices (such as its IPAddress) connected to the same network

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for gathering a list of the IP addresses of other connected devices on the phone. You'd need to communicate to an access point, switch, router, etc. that had an exposed API for providing you a list of known/active connections (and apparently, some devices won't report devices that have static IP addresses). You'll find that many software tools which report other devices on the network just scan for them (by taking a range of IP addresses), probing IP addresses, fetching MAC addresses, etc. You would need to do the same on Windows Phone.

Comment: Sorry i don't have idea about this scanning or probe. Is there any blog explaining this or any links would be very helpful for me to proceed...

Comment: What are you trying to build? In many environments, creating a port scanner is considered a hostile network action.

Comment: Actually my goal is to communicate with those devices using Tcp/IP protocol once i found the ip addresses.

Comment: Sure, but what are you trying to build? Rather than scanning a network segment for Ip addresses, maybe there's a better way?

Comment: I'm trying to build a chat application inside a local network.so what is the best approach ?

Comment: That really is a much broader question beyond what you originally asked. The best choice is to have a centralized hub server that helps "clients" find each other, and depending on network configuration, helps transmit traffic between devices.